# Android Navigation does not run

Tags: android, kotlin

I am working with a rent calcualtions app, and having problems with navigation actions between to fragments. I have a back button but when I try to call the action nothing happends. It's strange becouse my other back button between fragsments works. Do you guys see any problem with my code?

I am going to implement Data-binding, ViewModul, LiveData, ev. LiveData Transformations.

Please know that this prosject is ongoing so all code is not set up yet.

annuitetPlanFragment.kt

```
package com.example.lnognedbetalingsplan

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.navigation.fragment.findNavController
import kotlin.math.pow

class annuitetPlanFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {



        val viewAnnuitetPlan = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_annuitet_plan, container, false)
        val buttonTilbake = viewAnnuitetPlan.findViewById<Button>(R.id.tilbakeTilAnnuitet)


        buttonTilbake.setOnClickListener {
            findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_annuitetPlanFragment_to_annuitetFragment)
        }


        var loanNumber = 200000
        var rent = 3.6
        var terminer = 12
        var r = rent / 100

        var x = 1 + (1 + r).pow(terminer)
        var y = x / rent
        var terminbelop = loanNumber / y
        var avdrag = terminer * terminbelop - loanNumber

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_annuitet_plan, container, false)
    }
}
```

navigation.xml

```
 <fragment
        android:id="@+id/annuitetPlanFragment"
        android:name="com.example.lnognedbetalingsplan.annuitetPlanFragment"
        android:label="fragment_annuitet_plan"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_annuitet_plan" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_annuitetPlanFragment_to_annuitetFragment"
            app:destination="@id/annuitetFragment"
            app:popUpTo="@id/annuitetFragment"
            app:popUpToInclusive="true" />
        <argument
            android:name="belop"
            app:argType="integer" />
    </fragment>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in annuitetPlanFragment.kt change return onCreateView() function to

```
return viewAnnuitetPlan
```